# Getting an object key based on subarray value

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, jq

I have a JSON defining some services:

```
{
  "services": {
    "main_content_renderer.off_canvas": {
      "class": "Drupal\\settings_tray\\Render\\MainContent\\OffCanvasRenderer",
      "arguments": [
        "@title_resolver",
        "@renderer"
      ],
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "render.main_content_renderer",
          "format": "drupal_dialog.off_canvas"
        }
      ]
    },
    "access_check.settings_tray.block.settings_tray_form": {
      "class": "Drupal\\settings_tray\\Access\\BlockPluginHasSettingsTrayFormAccessCheck",
      "tags": [
        {
          "name": "access_check",
          "applies_to": "_access_block_plugin_has_settings_tray_form"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to write a `jq` program which returns `access_check.settings_tray.block.settings_tray_form` for the input `access_check`.

I tried various things  but I either get `jq: error (at <stdin>:20): Cannot index array with string "name"` or just a syntax error.

Examples:

`jq '.services| to_entries|map(select(.value.tags.[].name == "access_check")))'`

This leads to a syntax error: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:`

Or `jq '.services| to_entries|map(select(.value.tags|.name == "paramconverter"))'` results in

`jq: error (at <stdin>:20): Cannot index array with string "name"`

Edit: while the example doesn't show there can be multiple tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.  If the following filter is in `filter.jq`

```
  .services
| keys[] as $k
| .[$k]
| select(.tags[]?.name == $name)
| $k
```

and the sample data is in `data.json` then the command

```
$ jq -Mr --arg name 'access_check' -f filter.jq data.json
```

produces

```
access_check.settings_tray.block.settings_tray_form
```

Comment: Thanks, based on all this I posted a complete shell script for grepping services by tags in Drupal 8 to https://gist.github.com/chx/31bd9db5c8e5e388875a401a3ef88778

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your inputs and outputs, you want a service name, if it contains a given tag name.

I would write it like so.

```
$ jq --arg name "access_check" '
.services | to_entries[] | select(any(.value.tags[].name; . == $name)).key
' input.json
```

You were close with your attempts, but there were some syntax issues:

1. `.value.tags.[].name`
   By having the dot before the `[]`, the syntax is now invalid. It should have been `.value.tags[].name`.
2. `.value.tags|.name`
   `tags` is an array, it may not have a property called `name`.